# Extend parsing command to multiple files

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

There are a number of files I use which can all be parsed into three files (per input file) with:

```
third_file_1_1.txt
first_file_1_2.txt....
```

in an automated process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FILENAME`](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_11.html#SEC108) builtin variable to know what file you are currently processing. This allows you to do:

```
awk '/^[01]+$/ {print > "third_"FILENAME; next}/ [...]' $(<list.txt)
```